# Can't reach website from outside of the network

Tags: web-hosting, server, ip-address, iis

I've created a website on IIS on my server, and can access this through my server to prove that the website is running fine locally.

I have set up these bindings on the site:

[image]

I've followed advice from other sites and stackoverlow itself to open port 90.

However, I still can't access this site externally outside the servers network using that IP address. Does anyone know why?

Answer (score 2):

That IP address (`192.168.0.168`) is a private IP address that is not available externally.

Depending on your network setup you will need one of the following:

- Assign a different public IP address to that server
- Set up port forwarding on your router
- Set up a reverse proxy from some other web server on your network that is already publicly accessible

If you don't want the port number (`:90`) to be part of the URL, you should change the server to run on the default ports: 80 for HTTP and 443 for HTTPS.

Comment: Thank you for answering, this may be a dumb question but how do I assign a public IP to the server? Is it something that can be acheivable through server manager?

Comment: You would have to connect that server to a different router, different port on the router, or modify your routing tables.   What type of network do you have with what types of routers?